# Contents-Based and collaborative filtering recommendation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, collaborative-filtering

I'm working as a CRM consultant and I need to figure out how to write a query in SQL Server. However, while I'm looking how to implement it, I found out that given database won't provide ratings. As I know, without ratings I would not be able to find out recommendation.

So here is my question.

Is there any way to apply without ratings. What I found so far is that use both contents-based and collaborative filtering recommender system.

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you need some intelligent rating system or do you need a function in MSSQL to rate values in a table according to some condition?

Comment: I want to know is there any way to use CF recommendation without intelligent rating system and if can be implemented without rating system, then how to do it with MSSQL?

Comment: This might be very late, but collaborative filtering can be applied on other data. Like explicit user ratings, Implicit information from user actions: Browsing, Purchases. Note that negative information is only a very slight indicator, External information about items, External information about users? From: http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring11/G22.2580-001/lec6.html Also, maybe give this a read: https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/from-explicit-user-engagement-to-implicit-product-rating/